# How to make audio files play in the correct order using Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I have an array of imported audio files, and I'm trying to play them sequentially with the Web Audio API. I have some code which almost works, but it plays the sounds in the wrong order, seemingly randomly.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or if there's a better way to achieve my goal?

```
import soundA from './assets/soundA.mp3'
import soundB from './assets/soundB.mp3'
import soundC from './assets/soundC.mp3'

function playSoundsSequentially() {

    let mySounds = [soundA, soundB, soundC]

    const ctx = new window.AudioContext();
    let time = 0;
    mySounds.forEach(sound => fetch(sound).then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
                                        .then(buffer => ctx.decodeAudioData(buffer))
                                        .then(buffer => {
        let track = ctx.createBufferSource();
        track.buffer = buffer;
        track.connect(ctx.destination);
        track.start(ctx.currentTime + time);
        time += track.buffer.duration;
    }));
}
```

Update: My solution based on JMP's insight on using promises. I also ditched the forEach for a simple for loop because I am more comfortable with that.

```
import soundA from './assets/soundA.mp3'
import soundB from './assets/soundB.mp3'
import soundC from './assets/soundC.mp3'

function playSoundsSequentially() {

    let mySounds = [soundA, soundB, soundC]

    let promises = []
    for(let i = 0; i < mySounds.length; ++i) {
        promises.push(fetch(mySounds[i]).then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
                                        .then(buffer => ctx.decodeAudioData(buffer)));
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(buffer => {
        for(let i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
            let track = ctx.createBufferSource();
            track.buffer = buffer[i];
            track.connect(ctx.destination);
            track.start(ctx.currentTime + time);
            time += track.buffer.duration;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very similar to this question:

> [Why is AJAX in for loop executing in wrong order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73196385/why-is-ajax-in-for-loop-executing-in-wrong-order)

Your code assembles the tracks in the order they are returned, **not** in the order they were sent,

`Promise.all()` deals with an array of promises ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)), and is also a `Promise` itself, which is only fulfilled when all of the array elements are, returning an array in the original order.

Try

```
let mySounds = [soundA, soundB, soundC]

const ctx = new window.AudioContext();
let time = 0;
mySounds.forEach(sound => fetch(sound).then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
                                  .then(buffer => ctx.decodeAudioData(buffer)));
Promise.all(mySounds).then(buffer => {
    let track = ctx.createBufferSource();
    track.buffer = buffer;
    track.connect(ctx.destination);
    track.start(ctx.currentTime + time);
    time += track.buffer.duration;
});
```